# Set the column width of jQuery DataTables Column Filter

Tags: jquery, datatables

How to set the column width of jQuery DataTables Column Filter?

My code is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/aobmk2of/

```
...
dataTable.columnFilter({
  sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
  aoColumns: [
      { type: "select", width:"10px" },  
      { type: "select" },        
      { type: "select" },  
      { type: "select" },  
      { type: "select" }
  ]
});
...
```

But it's not working.

Thank you.

Comment: as I can see there is one value in dropdown list like "testingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtestingtesting". That's why it's become larger

Comment: @KushalVora, It's just for testing only. If so, is it can be set width of column filter? Sorry, my english is not so good

Comment: Column width will be set based on your header width.

Comment: @KushalVora, In th tag? I try like this : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/aobmk2of/5/). But it's not working.

Comment: I have posted answer, please check it.

Comment: @KushalVora, Thank you very much. It's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please apply this class.

```
#example select
{
    width:100px !important;
}
```